# Applications that support low fidelity qubits generated by UQCM

Tags: qiskit, applications, no-cloning-theorem, cloning

I am studying Universal quantum cloning machines. I have found that two imperfect clones can be generated with fidelity of 83.33%. Where can we use these imperfect clones in quantum worlds? Can we use them for QKD for example?

Comment: related paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.2956.pdf